# Jquery not appending timestamp for cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to send an ajax request using sortable from jquery-ui. When I re-sort a list, for some reason, the ajax call isn't appending timestamp onto the querystring to avoid caching. Why won't this code work?

```
           $('#categorylist').sortable({
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                update:function(e, ui){

                    var categorylist = $('#categorylist').sortable('serialize', {attribute:'data-id'});

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'actions_category.php?action=rank',
                        method:'post',
                        data:categorylist,
                        cache:false
                    });

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only append the time stamp for GET and HEAD requests. It should not be needed for other types of requests except in IE8 for POST requests where you have already issued a GET request against the URL.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Note the supported HTTP Methods

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
Type: Boolean
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with **HEAD** and **GET** requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.